# Java. Canvas. JFrame

Tags: java, canvas, jframe

Код ниже рисует линию, каждую секунду новую.
Как можно сделать, чтобы новая линия добавлялась к старой?
*То есть хочу видеть через условно двадцать секунд - двадцать линий.*

1) Нужно добавлять значения для отрисовки в массив и каждый раз перерисовывать, как в закомментированной части,
2) или можно использовать старый **canvas** и рисовать поверх его.

Если второй вариант то как это можно сделать?

```java
package draw;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    static class MyCanvas extends Canvas {
        // условный массив со значениями
        // int4[] values = new int4[];
        // public void addValue(...) { // };
        static int x1 = 10;
        static int x2 = 20;
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            //  for (int4 val: values) {
            //        g.drawLine(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3])
            //  }
            g.drawLine(x1, x2, 200,200);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("nameOf");
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        Canvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // canvas.addValue(...);
            MyCanvas.x1 = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            MyCanvas.x2 = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            canvas.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема первого метода в том, что планируется использовать достаточно большие массивы. А как рисовать поверх старого полотна, я не могу понять.

Comment: Попробуйте завести коллекцию объектов и добавлять их в цикл
frame.add(new Canvas());
Это перенести в конструктор
x1 = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
В конце цикла
canvas.repaint();

Answer (score 0):

Нашел примерное решение, без объявления коллекции. Использовать в цикле:

```
canvas.getGraphics().drawLine(x1,x2,y1,y2);
```

Только результат не сохранится, если вызвать метод .repaint()
*(например, изменить размер окна, что автоматически вызовет перерисовку)*

```java
package draw;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    static class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval((int)(Math.random() * 100),(int)(Math.random() * 100),(int)(Math.random() * 100),(int)(Math.random() * 100));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("nameOf");
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            canvas.getGraphics().drawLine((int)(Math.random() * 100),(int)(Math.random() * 100), 200,200);
            System.out.println("---");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

В данном примере, для отрисовки новой линии, нужно ввести любое значение с клавиатуры в консоль.